# Dynamic EDM model creation in dotnet core

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata

I've seen the example at https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation for dynamic Odata route and model generation.

I need the same for dot net core but since Asp.net and Asp.net core vary in terms of the classes/routing etc. I'm unable to translate this code to dot net core.

Can anybody provide some guidance ?

My Startup.cs Configure method has this -

```
        IEdmModel model = this.GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices);

        IList<IODataRoutingConvention> routingConventions = new List<IODataRoutingConvention>();
        routingConventions.Insert(0, new MatchAllRoutingConvention());
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", model, new CustomPathHandler(), routingConventions));
```

CustomPathHandler.cs -

```
public class CustomPathHandler : DefaultODataPathHandler
{
    public override ODataPath Parse(string serviceRoot, string odataPath, IServiceProvider requestContainer)
    {
        var path =  base.Parse(serviceRoot, odataPath, requestContainer);
        return path;
    }

    public override string Link(ODataPath path)
    {
        return base.Link(path);
    }
}
```

ODataEndpointController.cs -

```
public class ODataEndpointController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute]
    public EdmEntityObjectCollection Get()
    {
        // Get entity set's EDM type: A collection type.            
        ODataPath path = Request.ODataFeature().Path;
        IEdmCollectionType collectionType = (IEdmCollectionType)path.EdmType;
        IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType = collectionType.ElementType.AsEntity();

        // Create an untyped collection with the EDM collection type.
        EdmEntityObjectCollection collection =
            new EdmEntityObjectCollection(new EdmCollectionTypeReference(collectionType));

        // Add untyped objects to collection.
        DataSourceProvider.Get(entityType, collection);

        return collection;
    }
```

MatchAllRoutingConvention.cs

```
public class MatchAllRoutingConvention : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public IEnumerable<ControllerActionDescriptor> SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)
    {
        ControllerActionDescriptor test = new ControllerActionDescriptor();
        test.ControllerName = "ODataEndpoint";
        return new List<ControllerActionDescriptor> { test }.AsEnumerable();

    }

}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here ? When I try to hit http://localhost:port/odata/Products I get some **source is null** error

Edit (15-Jan):

Modifying the MatchAllRoutingConvention as below redirected the routing as required but so do any $metadata requests (which throw an exception). And $filter queries don't work either. So any pointers/tips would be helpful -

```
public class MatchAllRoutingConvention : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public IEnumerable<ControllerActionDescriptor> SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)
    {
        ControllerActionDescriptor odataControllerDescriptor = new ControllerActionDescriptor
            {
                ControllerName = "ODataEndpoint",
                ActionName = "Get",
                Parameters = new List<ParameterDescriptor>(),
                FilterDescriptors = new List<FilterDescriptor>(),
                BoundProperties = new List<ParameterDescriptor>(),
                MethodInfo = typeof(ODataEndpointController).GetMethod("Get"),
                ControllerTypeInfo = typeof(ODataEndpointController).GetTypeInfo()
            };

            return new List<ControllerActionDescriptor> { odataControllerDescriptor };

    }

}
```

Comment: OData support in ASP.NET Core is still pre-release. (Although it has apparently now made it to beta status, which is something, considering SignalR is still in alpha.) ASP.NET Core is a different beast entirely, and the sample code you're looking at is for the stable OData in ASP.NET MVC. Long and short, quite a lot, if not everything entirely, has likely changed. Unfortunately, since it is pre-release, documentation is also very much lacking. You're pretty much out on your own here. If you need OData now, I'd recommed sticking with Web Api for the time being.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, and I'm hoping someone has a better understanding of Odata and the classes involved to kind of nudge me in the right direction here.
Sadly, the words prelease, beta, undocumented do not register with my 'superiors'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as an answer since I haven't seen any responses and hopefully this would help someone. I modified the MatchAllRoutingConvention class as below -

```
public class MatchAllRoutingConvention : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public IEnumerable<ControllerActionDescriptor> SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)
    {
        if (routeContext.RouteData.Values["odataPath"] == null || 
            routeContext.RouteData.Values["odataPath"].ToString() == "$metadata")
            return new MetadataRoutingConvention().SelectAction(routeContext);

        IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionCollectionProvider =
            routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();

        IEnumerable<ControllerActionDescriptor> actionDescriptors = actionCollectionProvider
            .ActionDescriptors.Items.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
            .Where(c => c.ControllerName == "ODataEndpoint");

        return actionDescriptors;
    }

}
```

This serves metadata requests correctly as well as simple entity requests. This doesn't however respond to $filter, $select etc. From what I understand the ODataQueryOptions class is used to apply OData filtering etc but they won't work on non-CLR classes which this is. So not sure if there is a solution for this problem.

[Edit]
So I've managed a sort of hack to get around this filtering issue. There is this library [LinqToQueryString](http://linqtoquerystring.net/) which you apply on an IQueryable, not EdmEntityObjectCollection obviously (it's not that easy).

I first load my data into a Dictionary, there's an example on their site to do that. Apply the OData query options string on that dictionary first, Then I Load the filtered result into my entities and then into the EdmEntityObjectCollection

```
    var list = new List<IEdmEntityObject>();
    var dataList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    // Load data in Dictionary
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
         var dataItem = new Dictionary<string, object>();

         // Load data

         dataList.Add(dataItem);
    }

    var filteredDataList = dataList.AsQueryable().LinqToQuerystring(oDataQuery);

    // Now add filtered/sorted etc data in EdmEntityObject
    foreach (var item in filteredDataList)
    {
         var entity = new EdmEntityObject(entityType);
         foreach (var key in item.Keys)
            entity.TrySetPropertyValue(key, item[key].ToString());
         list.Add(entity);
    }
```